# Rails-6 Unpermitted parameters on GET request

Tags: strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-6

I am recently upgrading a Rails `v5.2.3` application to Rails `v6.0.2`. After following the steps described in Rails Upgrade guide, when I start the rails server and performs a GET request, I get `Unpermitted parameters: :page, :sort, :beds, :baths, :floors`

- Is Rails-6 now forcing strong parameters on GET requests as well?
- Is there any way to pass/permit all parameters on every GET request in my application from a single source (possibly define some config settings in config folder) instead of using `params.permit` on each method?

Here's the backtrace:

```
Started GET "/search?page=1&sort=mp&beds%5B%5D=4&baths%5B%5D=4&floors%5B%5D=2"
Processing by BuildingsController#search as HTML
Parameters: {"page"=>"1", "sort"=>"mp", "beds"=>["4"], "baths"=>["4"], "floors"=>["2"]}
[Unpermitted parameters: :page, :sort, :beds, :baths, :floors
```

App Details:

- ruby 2.6.5
- rails 6.0.2
- bootsnap 1.4.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can add in each controller parameters `def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:page, :sort, :beds, :baths, :floors)
    end`

Comment: I don't think I have to do it for each controller's action! there must be some config level setting for this to work or may be inside application_controller

Comment: @KamalPanhwar It also seems like you haven't read my entire question! I am facing this on GET request and the solution you've provided works with POST request

Answer (score 1):

After investigating and spending some time on this, I came to know

- it's not Rails-6 specific.
- GET request in Rails-6 won't throw Unpermitted parameter error.
- I was using this line in controller `redirect_to no_search_results_path(params.permit.except(:action, :controller)) and return` and this was causing error. I am now using `redirect_to no_search_results_path(params.to_enum.to_h.except(:action, :controller)) and return` and all seems to work now.